# Do questions about the community forums belong here?

Tags: discussion

Should we close questions that are more about the Sitecore community forums/kb etc... than just about the actual CMS/Coding questions?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the answer to this question depends on resolving this question I asked earliwe:

**[What topics can I ask about on Sitecore Stack Exchange?](https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/)**

If we had a comprehensive list of [**allowed topics**](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) listed on the help page, it would be clear what's allowed and what isn't.

In my opinion, the scope of Sitecore Stack Exchange should be limited to questions about Sitecore *as a product*.

Community-related questions, for one, are prone to be opinion-based. They don't have a technical component, and answers to such questions will not be used as part of solution implementation process.

I believe that questions about Sitecore as a community do not belong on Sitecore Stack Exchange.

Comment: I am going back and forth here. I do believe that if it has to do with Sitecore, it should be allowed, but I really was talking about the product itself, not the company. The Community site I think is too out of scope for this particular FAQ board. - And I agree, a concrete list of allowed topics that can be used in scope should definitely be defined in the wiki.

Answer (score 2):

People wanted a Sitecore Stack Exchange in part to be able to ask questions that could not be on Stack Overflow (where you had to ask coding questions). So I think a non-coding question is absolutely fine.

That being said, I would say that a question about the community forums should be posted on the community forums. That is fairly straight-forward. There is a direct facility to ask about the site on the site itself.

For questions about the KB site, however, I see that as more open. There is no real capacity to discuss the KB site on the KB site, so having questions here on Stack Exchange probably makes sense. It could also be asked on the Community Forums, but I don't see that it is invalid to be asked here.

Similarly, a question about the documentation sites should probably also be allowed to be asked on Stack Exchange.

Comment: In regard to the KB, it really depends what sort of a question it is. For example, if the question is about a fix listed on the KB, then it is a technical question that has a merit on its own. If the question is about the KB as a site, then such questions should be discussed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This came up in Slack. Thanks for posting.

I look at this as a very *meta* question.

**If I'm having a problem with *Site A* I should go ask about it on *Site B* instead of asking on *Site A* which has facilities to ask that question.**

At first, my initial reaction is that if it's **Sitecore** related, it should be relevant here as a question.  That's if we are treating this as a true FAQ site.  However, after thinking about it, I come to the conclusion that's a question better asked on *Site A*.

Secondly, one can utilize other social avenues like `Slack` to route where that question might go.

It's an interesting question.

Answer (score -2):

My thought also we should allow ask questions about anything related to Sitecore here. As Jay S mention, one of our main arguments against using SO was, it only allows to ask coding related questions.

Other point is, we should make this SE site for **single access point** for every question about Sitecore. Otherwise, users have to go to different sites for different purposes does make no sense.