# Questions about third party tools used with Sitecore

Tags: discussion, community-guidelines

Should we ask questions about other development tools used in parallel with Sitecore here? I have sent a question to the slack community about some issues with Git and serialization files. It's not strictly a Sitecore question, but it is still related. Should we post these sort of questions here?
I have read [this](https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-topics-can-i-ask-about-on-sitecore-stack-exchange) questions, but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is directly related to Sitecore, e.g. it is about working with Serialization of Sitecore Items and working with Git/TFS/VCS, then it a valid question for this StackExchange.

If the question is about general files and working with Git then it would be better asked on StackOverflow or the appropriate StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

On other *.SE sites it's common practice to allow free 3rd party tools questions, but not paid-for 3rd party tools questions. The reason is that paid for tools often have a support organization/community themselves and which should be cared for for those who have bought the tool.

## Update

The Sitecore community and Sitecore itself rely on 3rd party tools which differs from other frameworks. Learning this, it's probably better to allow 3rd party questions and answers in sitecore.stackexchange.com too.

Comment: I think questions about commercial tools (Visual Studio, TeamCity, TDS, Coveo etc.) could be highly relevant in the context of SSE.

Comment: Please note, that Sitecore is a paid tool in the first place, yet it is so complex it has a number of different channels where you can ask for support

Comment: I agree to what your arguments are since Sitecore is in a sense a third party product which is different from SharePoint which I'm referring to. Maybe it should be allowed here on Si? I'll alter my answer based on your comments - thank you

Comment: I think if we want to give users/the community the best experience, support for third party tools should be allowed. Here is a possible approach provided by [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support). Also we wouldn't want to introduce bias where TDS questions are not allowed but Unicorn questions are. This would not be good for the community.